# Possible combinations of a list in Python

Tags: python

Given a list: 
Ex: [1,2,3,4].

Print the following:
[], [1], [1,2], [1,2,3], [1,2,3,4], [2], [2,3], [2,3,4] and so on

Basically we need to get all the combinations.

Comment: you want all combinations or consecutive combinations???

Comment: Are your input values always consecutive?

Answer (score 1):

using `itertools.combinations`:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> my_list = [1,2,3,4]
>>> [ list(x) for i in range(len(my_list)+1) for x in itertools.combinations(my_list,i) ]
[[], [1], [2], [3], [4], [1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [2, 3], [2, 4], [3, 4], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4], [1, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

if you want consecutive:

```
>>> [[]]+[ my_list[i:j] for i in range(len(my_list)) for j in range(i+1,len(my_list)+1) ]
[[], [1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4], [2], [2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3], [3, 4], [4]]
```

Comment: Your solution includes sublists like `[1,4]`, while it seems that the OP is looking for sublists that only have consecutive integers.

Comment: @Akavall but OP also mentioned need to get all combination

Answer (score 0):

This post explains how:
[How to get all possible combinations of a list’s elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464864/python-code-to-pick-out-all-possible-combinations-from-a-list)

```
[[x for x in itertools.combinations([1,2,3,4], y)] for y in range(4)]
```

That will provide the answer.
`itertools.combinations([1,2,3,4], y)` will provide all the combinations of `y` elements.
`range(4)` will provide the range 1 through 4
The nested list comprehension iterates through the number of elements to combine and the combinations themselves.

The output is:

```
[[()],
 [(1,), (2,), (3,), (4,)],
 [(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 4)],
 [(1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 4), (1, 3, 4), (2, 3, 4)]]
```

Then we can flatten the list with `chain.from_iterable`, as stated in this post: [Making a flat list out of list of lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python)

```
list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([[x for x in itertools.combinations([1,2,3,4], y)] for y in range(4)]))
```

Final output:

```
[(), (1,), (2,), (3,), (4,), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 4), (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 4), (1, 3, 4), (2, 3, 4)]
```

Answer (score 0):

If your input values are always consecutive, you can try the following idea:

```
result = []

for i in xrange(1, 6):
    for j in xrange(1, 6):
        if i > j:
            result.append(range(j, i))

print [[]] + sorted(result)
```

Result:

```
[[], [1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4], [2], [2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3], [3, 4], [4]]
```